# Lessons Learned through SO integration?

Tags: discussion

There have been a few questions asked on stackoverflow.com and programmers.stackexchange.com that have made me wish there was a way to perform a Lessons Learned "session" with the original authors. For example, if someone asked about redesigning an application, or rewriting from scratch, it would be nice if there was a way to associate a blog or **informal** wiki with that user in which they could talk about how everything went.

I realize they could always create their own blog and attach it to their profile but I can't help to think that it would bring more people together if there was a way to easily integrate SO with a less formal dialogue about their success/failure regarding a specific question, perhaps only after they've accepted an answer and a certain amount of time has passed.

Is such a website in the works or ever thought about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Damiean that a personal blog, and linking to it, is the right answer here. Adding personal blogging capabilities is something that is unlikely to ever get implemented on SO, because it's so far beyond the mission of providing a Q&A site.

I would link to it like this:

> @User's answer worked for me. I ran into additional issues with the flubbergargle (as discussed) but otherwise it went fine. I covered the necessary steps in my [blog](http://www.blogger.com).

Answer (score 1):

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I do appreciate this link. While it is in the realm of what I am talking about, the chat is more about instance gratification of communication. I guess I'm talking more about a way to blog about a question. We answer so many questions, people accept certain ones and we never find out what happened.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogger.com/

He'll just need to link to it.